# Why does zero - zero become nan in risc-v?

Tags: assembly, embedded, riscv

As it is shown in the following picture, I subtract fa0 (i.e. f10) register from itself to set it to zero. The register was already zero, but after subtraction, it became `NaN`. So, can anyone explain why `zero - zero = NaN`?

Update: I am using `qemu-riscv32-static` for simulation.

[image: gdb]

Comment: That seems mysterious.  Do other FP operations work correctly, and get shown correctly by your debugger?  Note that FP `x-=x` only works when the inputs aren't NaN or infinity, so it's not a safe zeroing idiom in general.  It should be giving zero for `0. - 0.`, though.  It looks like you're using GDB correctly, checking the register value before the instruction, and right after.  (`display $fa0` will get it to print the value after every single-step, in case that helps.  Like maybe if an interrupt handler corrupted it?)

Comment: It would be better to copy/paste from your terminal as text, not just an image.  Or at least quote the relevant instruction and the `i r fa0` result.

Comment: You could also try `qemu -singlestep -d cpu,fpu` for a ton of output. Works for me, by the way. You might also want to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What exact versions of GDB and QEMU are you using ?

Comment: BTW, GCC and clang agree (https://godbolt.org/z/8GK3e4obP) that the best way to zero an FP register is `fmv.w.x fa0, zero`, at least without any pre-conditions like known register values.